# Display Available User Defined Types in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, object-relational-model

I want to get all the user defined type I have defined so far. Please tell me how to display it?
And I want to know how to drop a UDT?

```
drop type <type name?
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query `dba_types`, `all_types`, or `user_types` depending on what privileges you have and what types you are looking for.  `user_types` will list the types that are owned by the current user.  `all_types` will list all the types that the current user has access to which will include types owned by other users that the current user has been granted privileges on.  `dba_types` will list all the types in the database but you would need privileges to be able to query the `dba_*` views such as the `select any dictionary` privilege or the `select_catalog_role` role.